# Selectively record commands and output from terminal to MySQL table

Tags: linux, bash, terminal, mysql

In some situations I would like to store complete commands and output from terminal sessions in a MySQL database.

Ideally I would just copy the command and output from the terminal to my clipboard then just paste into a simple bash script that would update the relevant field.

I have experimented with using the read function in bash, see below. However when pasting multiple lines into the read it does not parse the line breaks correctly.

```
#!/bin/bash

read -e -p "name: " name
read -e -p "output: " ouput

mysql -u example@localhost << EOF
use database;
insert into table (name, output) values('$title', '$output');

EOF
```

I know this is not elegant, but would really useful reference for me in the future.

Perhaps somebody could shed some light on a better way to get this done...

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To paste multilines in a variable, I would do :

```
#!/bin/bash


echo -en 'Paste your multiline content and ^D to submit >>> '
content="$(cat)"
echo "$content"
```